# Swift JSON Parsing Access Array

Tags: json, swift

I am pulling a JSON file from [Open - Elevation](https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=41.161758,-8.583933) However I am unable access the individual segments of the array from the data I pulled. My current view controller has the JSON parsing code in it and it also allow me to get a read out of the whole array it self.

```
struct ElevationArray: Decodable {
    let results: [results]
}

struct results: Decodable {
    let latitude: Double
    let longitude: Double
    let elevation: Double

    init(json: [String: Any]){
      latitude = json["latitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
      longitude = json["longitude"] as? Double ?? 0.0
      elevation = json["elevation"] as? Double ?? 0.0

    }
}

class FlightInfo: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var Lat: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Long: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var Elevation_label: UILabel!

    var elevationmain: Double?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        Lat.text = "\(publocation.latitude)"
        Long.text = "\(publocation.longitude)"

        ElevationJSON()


    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func ElevationJSON(){

        let jsonURLString = "https://api.open-elevation.com/api/v1/lookup?locations=41.161758,-8.583933"
        guard let url = URL(string: jsonURLString) else {return}

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            //perhaps check err
            //also perhaps check response status 200 OK

            guard let data = data else { return }


            do {
                //let websiteDescription = try JSONDecoder().decode(WebsiteDescription.self, from: data)
               // print(websiteDescription.name, websiteDescription.description)

               let eleresults = try JSONDecoder().decode(ElevationArray.self, from: data)
               print(eleresults.results)

                let eletest = eleresults.results

                print(eletest)

                //self.elevationmain = Double(eleresults.results)
            } catch let jsonErr {
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }



            }.resume()
    }

}
```

This is the console output which I got when I ran the application with the array printed out. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDGqu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eleresults.results` (or `eletest`) is an array of `results`.

To access all of the data, use a loop:

```
for result in eletest {
    print(result.elevation)
}
```

If you just want the first result:

```
if let result = eletest.first {
    print(result.elevation)
}
```

BTW - your `results` struct should be renamed to something useful such as `Elevation` or anything more description than `results` (and note it should start with an uppercase letter.